# "Products" Title changed

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

[image]

How can I change this title? I would like to chage it "products" instead of "PRODUCTOos"

Comment: Hello,
Which WordPress locale do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Which WordPress locale do you use?
Spanish (es_ES) seems to be correctly translated: https://translate.wordpress.org/projects/wp-plugins/woocommerce/stable/es/default/?filters%5Bstatus%5D=either&filters%5Boriginal_id%5D=579432&filters%5Btranslation_id%5D=23145308
Are your translation up to date ?